# Why Webmaster Tools shows different data to different users?

Tags: google-search-console

We have a problem between marketing and development department in our StartUp: Google Webmaster Tools is showing different data to different users which are logged in.  Why is this happening and how we can prevent this in the future?

For example, one of the team members sees 6 messages in Google Webmaster Tools while other sees only 2 of them.

Comment: Do both have exactly the same set of sites registered (including sub-domains)?   Have you submitted sitemaps?

Comment: Hi Stephen, we have submitted sitemaps, although sometimes GWT give us different data even with the sitemaps info.

Answer (score 1):

When you say messages what messages are you referring to that your employees are seeing? Are they general notifications withing Google Webmaster Center? Or do they have to do with errors on the website such as 404's or other crawling errors?

If the messages are general account notifications they're most likely different due to the different emails logging in if access was shared.

It's also possible though I doubt that when they login some are connecting to different data centers which have data out of sync and are updating.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. Basically we have differences in the data even in the same page during the day (ex. differences in sitemap, 0 for one and submitted for other team member).

Answer (score 0):

We have almost 22 account for a single domain. Never came across such thing. Make sure the site or sub-domain is same and give Google some time if there is any discrepancy then it will surely resolved within next 48 hours.

Comment: The problem is that the access for the site: the same account is showing different data and apart from that we have different data between all the users.

Answer (score 0):

Google Webmaster Tools usually only shows sitemaps (and associated messages) to the person that submitted the sitemap.  Everybody could submit the same set of sitemaps.